# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Multiple parameters

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a unique Conditional formatting situation.

Columns E-H have check boxes as well as K-L
Columns I-J require various text in cell

With this:

```
=and($E3, $F3, $G3, $H3, $K3, $L3)
```

I can format the checkboxes if checked, but how do I incorporate if $I3 and $J3 have text into this formula?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this out:

```
=and($E3, $F3, $G3, $H3, $K3, $L3, ISTEXT($I3), ISTEXT($J3))
```

Comment: Yup, that is what I was missing. Thank you for your assistance rockinfreakshow!